# will_paginate, how to pass form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.86, Will_Paginate 2.3.15

I have a fairly large search form (text box, radio buttons, check boxes, collection_select, etc.).   I've added will_paginate in for the list of results.   Everything works fine except when moving to a new page the only param being sent is "page".   When moving to a new will_paginate page, the result is the query goes to defualt showing all records because none of the search form params are being sent.

For the Will_Pagenate links (<%= will_paginate @contacts %>), is it possible to somehow force all the params from a form to be sent (just as if the submit button is clicked)?  Or how should I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was looking around a found a mention of changing the "post" method of a form to a "get" method.   That was my problem - the search form selections are being preserved through will_paginate page changes now.

Comment: Please link to where you found it in the docs and mark this answer as the correct one.